Tkinter menu command, set string to None
I have this code I'd like to condense if possible:
def ForgetPassword():
    """ Clear sudo password for extreme caution """
    global SUDO_PASSWORD
    SUDO_PASSWORD = None

self.tools_menu.add_command(label="Forget sudo password", underline=0,
                            font=g.FONT, command=ForgetPassword, state=tk.DISABLED)

Rather than using command=ForgetPassword, is it possible for something like command=SUDO_PASSWORD=NONE?

No.  The command= option is a function to be called later, and you have no option other than a full def here because a lambda cannot assign to a global variable.

Like jasonharper said, you need a full def for this but there are workarounds. A terrible approach would be to make SUDO_PASSWORD into a mutable object like a list containing only 1 string. Then you can do something like command=SUDO_PASSWORD_LIST.clear since list objects have a clear method.

@TheLizzard I've used lists before to share variables between inner functions. SUDO_PASSWORD being a list would allow you to put the expiry time as the second value.

Just use a function. It’s a couple of lines of code, makes your code more understandable, and also makes it easier to test and debug. Functions are tools to make your job easier. Use them.
